# How to get selected "CheckBoxes" from tree view using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using asp TreeView control. I want to get selected "checboxes" values at client side. How do I get selected values from TreeView?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your treeview has id `treeviewid`

```
$('#treeviewid input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
   alert($(this).val());    
});
```

Comment: I am getting "On" as output. I want value of checkbox which is binding while creating treeview. tn.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(Sector.SectorName, Sector.SectorId.ToString())); @

Comment: You can use attr to get the attributes e.g. you want to get attribute name, alert($(this).attr('name'));

Comment: adil-> I want SectorID , but when I see in source view I can't find it.

Comment: Check it might be given to some other html element, if you can find it in source then we can access it. If it is not source then it is impossible to get it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use clientId

```
$('#<%=MyTreeView.ClientID%>').find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).val());    
});
```

Comment: Yes, but .find selector doesn't need "input" and should look like .find(':checkbox:checked').

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following code to determine all the checked checkboxes:

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: So simple, so nice.